# Get rid of proxy popup in ios simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, proxy

I'm behind a corporate firewall and all network traffic goes thru the main proxy.  In my iOS simulator, I get proxy popups a few times each time I run my app.  The thing is, my app doesn't make any network calls (yet), and doesn't import any network frameworks.  In fact, I can reproduce this by making a new project in XCode using one of the standard templates and run it straight away; it'll still prompt for the proxy credentials every time.

In my OSX network settings, I've obviously set my proxy credentials in all the different protocols (HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, Socks, RTSP, Gopher).  I found that I needed to put the domain and backslash before my username to allow web access in any OSX browsers etc...so given that I did that and then the OSX proxy prompts went away and I was allowed access, I would have thought that the iOS simulator would just inherit those settings...?

Any ideas?

One more bit which may be unrelated: we haven't yet figured out how to get access to the App Store on this Mac; despite supposedly getting past the proxy, any use of the App Store just results in timeouts and we can't even see the "home page".  I'm wondering if somehow the iOS simulator is making similar network calls using some other protocol that is like the App Store...?  (I would have thought App Store would have been HTTPS but I don't know).

Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you put *.apple.com in your proxy passthrough list, the simulator will stop whining about it.

Like you, I can't get the Apple Store to work through our corporate proxy either. I've worked around it by using a wireless network that doesn't use a proxy when I have to use the App Store.

I've found plenty of other things in the OS that don't work through our proxy.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was driving me crazy.  Great fix! :)

Comment: `*.apple.com` also blocks all websites/connection.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found another way **without touching the proxy settings**!

I'm working on a Mac with OSX-El Capitan so maybe in other versions these steps might be slightly different:

- Go to **System Preferences**
- Go to **Network**
- Choose your connection (Wireless/Ethernet/Thunderbolt-Ethernet)
- Click on **Advanced Options**
- Go to the tab **Proxies**
- The two boxes **Automatically detect proxy** (for the internet connection on your mac) and **Web-Proxy (HTTP)**
- Insert your login credentials at **Web-Proxy (HTTP)**.

This reduced the occurence of the Proxy-PopUp greatly on all the 3 macs I work with. (At least it doesn't appear periodically anymore when I start my app from xcode)